# which one is better in performance: using function or exact code?

Tags: c++, performance, performance-testing

I write codes for 3D simulations so my codes is full of something like this:

May using function cause overhead? And why?

"a" is a 3D pointer.

**Update**

definition of function

```
double update_a(double a[][JE][KE],...)
{

for(i=1;i<IE;i++){
    for(j=1;j<JE;j++){
        for(k=1;k<KE;k++){
            curl_h=(hz[i][j][k]-hz[i][j-1][k]-hy[i][j][k]+hy[i][j][k-1]);
            idxl[i][j][k]=idxl[i][j][k]+curl_h;
            a[i][j][k]=gj3[j]*gk3[k]*dx[i][j][k]+gj2[j]*gk2[k]*.5*(curl_h+gi1[i]*idxl[i][j][k]);
        }}}
```

IE=JE=KE=200

which one is better :

```
 int main()
{
 update_a(...)}
```

or

```
int main(){
 for (i=0; i<200; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<200; j++) {
        for (k=0; k<200; k++) {
             curl_h=(hx[i][j][k]-hx[i][j][k-1]-hz[i][j][k]+hz[i-1][j][k]);

                idyl[i][j][k]=idyl[i][j][k]+curl_h;
                a[i][j][k]=gi3[i]*gk3[k]*ey[i][j][k]+gi2[i]*gk2[k]*0.5*(curl_h+gj1[j]*idyl[i][j][k]);
        }
    }
}
 }
```

**UPdate2:**

My exact code looks like this:

```
int main()
    {
for(n=1;n<100000;n++){
     update_a(...);
update_a2(...);
.
.
.
update_a30(...);}}
```

Comment: What do you mean using function?

Comment: Can you post the alternatives?

Comment: Using a function *might* cause slight overhead. Pushing local variables on the stack, etc.

Comment: for example double update(double a){My for loops}

Comment: @Dismissile Not necessarily true due to optimization.

Comment: @Ehsan which 2 alternatives are you comparing? What function call?

Comment: I mean using a function (passes by value or passed by reference) and writing whole lines of for loops in main function of c++ code

Comment: To clarify, what exactly is inside the function call? Is the function call the computation on a(i,j,k), or the entire triple for-loop?

Comment: @void-pointer: see the fourth comment...

Comment: @void-pointer I add exact code in Edit

Comment: The only way to know is to test them both with a profiler. Just use a function because it's easiest to maintain, and if the profiler says this loop is bad *then* move on to testing different ways of writing it. Until then, nobody can really help you. Voting to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes no significant difference. The function is only called once, in `main`. So the function-call overhead, if there is any, is only paid once per run of the program. Compared with all the work that's needed to run the program, one extra function entry and return is nothing.

There is one way it could be non-trivial, which is if one of the arguments you haven't shown in `...` is passed by value and is really expensive to copy. The one that you have shown is just a pointer, though, so not expensive to copy.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have a question about your answer, you mentioned that " The function is only called once, in main. So the function-call overhead, if there is any, is only paid once per run of the program.", for executing my code with these such functions I have to call functions for about 3,000,000 times! May these large number of function calls cause decreasing the speed of my code?

Comment: @Ehsan: no, your main routine does not call `update_a` about 3 million times. It only calls it once. If you *still* won't show what your actual code does, I can't help. You'll have to answer the question for yourself. Don't think about how many times the function is called, think whether the function call overhead is likely to be a significant cost compared to what the function does when you call it. In your case, the function contains nested loops that do 8 million operations, so it is not significant. Then, run both versions of the code with a stopwatch, and see if your guess was correct.

Comment: Thanks for your response. My exact code has about 1500 lines; but I try to show you what exactly my code looks like. please look at update2

Answer (score 3):

Storing your code in functions *might* cause some overhead, which starts to build up if something is being called a thousand times a second, but do note there are many places suitable for various compiler optimizations which it will very likely perform because it is located in a loop (that's where the usual update logic functions are located for 3D simulations because it's perframe data). I would advise against actually doing anything about this, only if you find a problem during testing then you might go into "manual optimization mode".

But the most of the overhead will arise if you're indeed using a "3D" pointer (a T***) because it will only contiguously allocate the actual anon. array of pointers to pointers. That means that every indirection will cost you severely because the address of any given element cannot be calculated trivially as it would be with a T[m][n][q] array which is linearly laid out in memory (and can decay into a pointer, perhaps that's what you're referring to). Then you'll have an overhead due to the discrepancy between memory and CPU performance.

Comment: Because of contiguous form of my "3D" pointer I can avoid cache miss and use "mpi derived data types"

Answer (score 2):

The performance penalty of a function call is insignificant compared to the running time of the code you provided.

Comment: Irrelevant, because the function will not actually be called on any modern C++ compiler with the appropriate optimization flags. Also, the overhead associated with the function call can make quite a large difference in many examples of numerical codes.

Comment: It's not as simple as that, for a code like that caching plays some role in the time. Also, if it's called millions of times, even the call itself can cause overhead.

Comment: Depends how many function calls, of course, but if we imagine that the loops are going to stay where they are, and all the junk in the middle is going into a single function, then of course the overhead of a function call is small compared with at least 27 indirections (if there really are that many, I don't know what a "3D pointer" actually is), 6 multiplications that I can see, and sundry other arithmetic. There remains a question how much of that junk can be hoisted outside the inner loop by the compiler, of course -- there maybe less work to do than it seems at first glance.

Comment: @void-pointer: you say, "the function will not actually be called", the C++ abstract machine says, "the function call overhead might be zero". Potayto, potahto ;-)

Answer (score 2):

premature optimizations is bad!

You should use a function and only hand inline the code if it found to be and issue! (using profiling tools and performance testing)

Function overhead is negligible, especially so, considering you code.

Many compilers will inline functions as needed anyway. Meaning any in-lining you do is not going to effect performance, and will lead to maintenance  and code readability issues.

Comment: Micro optimizations aren't necessarily bad if they're not premature.

Answer (score 1):

**Assuming the function you're talking about is called inside the loop:**

On any modern C++ compiler, the function will almost certainly be inlined. Try it with g++ for example, and you should find that the machine code produced with the function call is identical to the machine code produced without the function call.

If the function call is outside the loop, whether or not the compiler decides to inline the function is dependent on the context in which the function is used.

Comment: For such an extensive loop, if it is used in many places? This seems very unlikely. If you don't force inlining by some construct I doubt it will be inlined

Comment: Especially if the loop is used in many places -- the compiler will determine that the function is "hot," and the chances of it being inlined will be increased dramatically. Have you tried the code with any recent version of g++? It's a very simple test to try before you comment.

Comment: Inlining is advantageous if body size is relatively small. If it's large, inlining is useful if it is only used once or twice (code duplication is minimal then), otherwise you gain almost nothing by inling but code-cache misses. And why should I provide compiled assembly for a comment if you don't even do it for an answer?

Comment: Sorry, I am a little confused here: I assumed that the function call is **inside** the loop. In this case, inlining will make a huge difference and the compiler is almost certainly going to inline the function. If the entire loop is itself one function, then whether or not the function gets inlined is dependent upon the context.

Comment: Now, in any case. putting it in a function will essentially let the compiler decide on whether it should be inlined or not. And the compiler is in almost all cases a better judge than we are. And if you really want it to make the best decision, you can pass profiling data as a hint with most recent compilers..

Answer (score 1):

Function call will slightly eat your performance for creating stack and other stuffs.

But in your case it doesn't matter because, you have only few lines of code(assuming).

Comment: @Ehsan: do you mean that you have the exact same 3 long lines of unreadable junk copied and pasted into 30 different places in your code? If so, then you *need* to common it up. If that turns out to be inefficient, next work out how to *efficiently* common it up! Absolute worst case scenario, you put it in a function, you can't find a way to avoid a function call overhead that's killing your performance, so you replace the function with an equivalent macro. You've at least avoided the code duplication. As far as the compiler is concerned the code is identical, so it will perform the same.

Comment: ... but that worst case is unlikely. Chances are you won't notice a performance difference by putting it in a function, it's just that nobody can promise you that you won't.

Comment: @SteveJessop I mean 30 such loops (not the same but like together). The loops that I posted them are update function of "a". If I run these loops once a time there is no problem. The problem comes out when I have to update my "a" and other parameters for 100000 times

Comment: @Ehsan: well, I still don't really understand what you're asking, then. You keep saying, "I have code A. Code B uses functions. Is it slower?". You've shown us part of code A, but you haven't shown us code B, and neither have you run them both to compare how long each takes. That's why you're getting a lot of generalities and guesswork. Just try it, and if you don't like the result ask a question about how to improve the code you've tried.